# append encoding on creation of xml file

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding

this code creates an xml file if it does not exist:

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    if(file_exists('test.xml')){
    $xmldoc->load('test.xml');
    } else {
    $xmldoc->loadXML('<root/>'); 
    }
```

however, i would also like `encoding="UTF-8"` to be appended automatically on creation of the file. how would one do this in php?

Comment: You don't have to, it's implicitly utf-8 when it's not specified.

Comment: @Artefacto: Or UTF-16, or UTF-32. Specifying it explicitly doesn't hurt anyone, though.

Comment: @Artefacto, when i insert arabic script into the xml file, it appears as garbled; but if i explicitly state `utf-8`, the arabic script in xml displays fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add/change the `<?xml encoding` value in the output of `saveHTML()`, you can set the [`encoding`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.encoding) property.

```
$xmldoc->load('test.xml');
$xmldoc->encoding= 'utf-8';
$xmldoc->save('test.xml');
```

However, as Artefacto said, in this case it's pointless. An XML file without an `<?xml encoding` declaration or a UTF-16 BOM *is* definitely UTF-8 and *all* XML parsers will read it that way(*). You will gain nothing by adding an explicit `encoding="utf-8"` parameter to the XML Declaration.

Whatever the method is you're using to test, it's not doing what you think it's doing. Maybe you're loading XML into a text editor and it's saving it out in a different encoding, or something? You need to look at where you're getting the strings from that are going into the DOM before you save it, and if they're not UTF-8 you need to convert them *then*.

(*: Well unless it's served via another protocol with a higher-priority charset specification method, like HTTP's `Content-Type` header. But in that case the `<?xml encoding` declaration is ignored anyway.)

Comment: thank you. that worked. i'm loading the xml in Notepad++. perhaps it maybe saving and outputting in a different encoding. how do i check this?

Comment: From Notepad++, click on the Encoding menu item.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a new UTF-8 encoded file, this should work:

```
$xmldoc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
if(file_exists('test.xml')){
    $xmldoc->load('test.xml');
} else {
    $xmldoc->loadXML('<root/>'); 
}
```

But if you are opening a file that is not encoded in UTF-8, you'll have problems with the output... so you'll want to check the encoding of the file if it exists, and if not, you can create it as UTF-8.

---

OK:

```
<?php
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    print  $xmlDoc->saveXML();
?>
```

outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: Wait... are you trying to create a UTF8 encoded file, or have the text "encoding="UTF-8" appear _in_ the file?

Comment: i'm trying to create the xml file with the text `encoding="UTF-8"` appearing at the top of the file.

Comment: OK - the problem with my first answer was that the UTF was in caps.  UTF-8 needs to appear as utf-8.

Comment: thanks NinjaCat, but i don't get your code. i'm already appending the nodes, all i want to do is append the text `encoding="utf-8"` automatically to the xml file which will be created. the text `encoding="utf-8"` doesn't appear, when i tried your code.

Comment: I updated the code again.  Are you saying if you use "$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');", that the XML header does not show utf-8 (case sensitive)?  If so, I am puzzled... what version of php are you using?

Comment: yes, that's what i'm saying. and if i insert arabic text, it appears all garbled in the xml file unless i explicity type `encoding="utf-8"`. using version 5.3.2 with notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by bobince is correct and great help.
you can also read $dom->encoding from the file you read or grab.
I also output it with the header();

```
$xmldoc->load('test.xml');
$encoding = $dom->encoding;

/* ... manipulate dom ... */

header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=". $encoding); 
echo $dom->saveXML();
```